# Refer to file variable by FileName.variable Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a file, where the variables are "static" in java sense, and I want to access them by the file name. I am giving an example.

```
private var user:User?= null// this is put directly inside the file
fun saveMe(user: User?){
    saveObject(user, USER_FILE)
    FileStorage.user = user// this method is not allowed. How to access the top level user variable from here?
}
```

I don't know if this has been asked before, I guess the question is clear, about accessing the top level variable from a function that has same name argument. **I don't want to rename either of the variables.**

Comment: how did you implement this "static in a java sense" variable?

Comment: The methods and variables are declared directly inside FileStorage.kt file. I am new to Kotlin, so may be not adapt to naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Wrap your file into `object`:

```
object FileStorage {
    // all your previous file content
}
```

Then `FileStorage.user` means exactly what you want.

Option 2 (if your file has a package declaration):

```
fun saveMe(user: User?){
    saveObject(user, USER_FILE)
    your.package.user = user
}
```

Option 3: add indirection:

```
private var user:User?= null
fun setTopLeverUser(_user: User?) { user = _user; }

fun saveMe(user: User?){
    saveObject(user, USER_FILE)
    setTopLevelUser(user)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Then in this case there is no provision to refer to File scope user variable from a function that has the same name? I got your point.

Comment: I added another option which I didn't think of initially. But no, there's no special provision.